How to solve integrating factor PDE
So I was trying to find a solution to this ODE,
$$\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=\dfrac{y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}}\iff (x^2+y^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}\,\mathrm dy-y^2\,\mathrm dx=0,$$
following the OP's method. Since the differentials aren't exact I thought we could find an integrating factor $\mu(x,y)$ to this problem by imposing
$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\mu(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}\right]=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}\left[-\mu y^2\right].$$
Without further calculations, we arrive at
$$(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}\mu_x+y^2\mu_y +[5 x(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}+2y]\mu=0.$$
Or in polar coordinates
$$\left(\dfrac{r^4}{\cos\theta}+r\sin\theta\right)\mu_r(r,\theta)+\left(\dfrac{\sin^2\theta}{\cos\theta}-\dfrac{r^3}{\sin\theta}\right)\mu_\theta(r,\theta) +(5 r^3\cos\theta+2\sin\theta)\mu=0.$$
One could even divide by $\mu$ and solve for $\ln\mu$.
What I was wondering now was what method could we use to solve this PDE. Maybe characteristics method or separation of variables?

I have yet to see or find a method where solving the resulting integrating factor PDE does not result in needing to solve the original ODE, not for lack of trying. Also, the equation can be taken to an Abel equation via the transformations $y=(u+z^{3/2}/(z^2+1)^{5/2})^2$, $x=(u+z^{3/2}/(z^2+1)^{5/2})^2/z\ $:
\begin{align}uu'_z-\left[\frac{z^{1/2}}{2(z^2+1)^{5/2}}+\frac{z^{1/2}(7z^2-3)}{2(z^2+1)^{7/2}}\right]u=\frac{z^2}{2(z^2+1)^5}\end{align}

Additionally, if you are going to try to solve the PDE you can cut out the middleman and seek the solution directly. Assuming a solution of the form $\psi(x,y)=C$, $\psi$ must satisfy the PDE $(x^2+y^2)^{5/2}\psi_x+y^2\psi_y=0$, which is slightly simpler than the one for $\mu$.

What's $C$ ? A constant? If so, how did you "get rid" of the $(...)\mu$ term?

$C$ is a constant; we are supposing that $\psi(x,y)=C$ is the first integral of the ODE. Taking a derivative yields $\psi_x+y'_x\psi_y=0$ under the chain rule, and we can substitute $y'_x$ from your ODE to arrive at the PDE for $\psi$. Seeking an integrating factor $\mu$ just happens to result in a closely related PDE. (For any ODE of the form $y'_x=f(x,y)$, not just this specific one).
